# IOS Webview crash: [DOMRange domRange]

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash

My webview randomly crashed when load web page, below is the crash. does anyone have clue ?

Thanks.

```
-[DOMRange domRange]:

** unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17043b940
2548 Aug  6 22:35:44 Insigma40de-iPhone PAAnydoorSDK_New[931] 
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DOM     Range domRange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17043b940'
2549         *** First throw call stack:
2550         (0x184c282d8 0x1963fc0e4 0x184c2f3a4 0x184c2c154 0x184b2eccc 0x189a337b4 0x189b0c3b4 0x189819cf8 0x1897ff0dc 0x189698720 0x189b094fc 0x18965c484 0x1     8965a830 0x189696898 0x189695f50 0x18966918c 0x18990a324 0x1896676a0 0x184be0240 0x184bdf4e4 0x184bdd594 0x184b092d4 0x18e3276fc 0x1896cefac 0x100041b70 0x1     96a7aa08)
2551 Aug  6 22:35:44 Insigma40de-iPhone ReportCrash[937] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
```

Comment: yet, i know the crash is caused by some early release object. but the question is, when the crash happens, my UIWebview and its delegate is there not been released, why this crash happened? in IOS programming, it seems apple just provides UIWebview and some delegate method API for programmer, so why the DOMRange crash happens? May it a UIWebview bug OR the HTML page it load causes the crash?

Answer (score -1):

This error means that the object was not found this method. It is likely that your object before calling the method has been released.

Comment: thanks, i know. but the question is, when the crash happens,  my UIWebview and its delegate is there not been released, why this crash happened? in IOS programming, it seems apple just provides UIWebview and some delegate method API for programmer, so why the DOMRange crash happens? May it a UIWebview bug OR the HTML page it load causes the crash?